# Is it some way to do async code for write to Stream?

Tags: c#, wpf, stream

I write some WPF editor, wich show come text.
But text stores at `Stream`.

So, here XAML code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectViewModel.Text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, because user can read and write some text at this redactor;

Here code where read and write text (as stream):

```
public String Text
{
    get
    {    
        var sr = new StreamReader(StreamObject.text, Encoding.UTF8, true);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    set
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            var str = value;
            var textStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(textStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {                                           
                writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
            }
            textStream.Position = 0;
            StreamObject.text = null;
            StreamObject.text = textStream;
            textStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So, when user type new word- code write to stream new data (clear old stream and create new).

But it get slow perfomance.
Should i use `async` (somehow) or other method to make perfomace better?

I know,that can use `LostFocus` property, but at that way user should to lost focus of `TextBox`.

Comment: Why store the text in a Stream in the first place?

Comment: @Clemens, it is store at DB. By design

Comment: Then convert it once right before it's stored in the DB, not on every single keystroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i use async (somehow) or other method to make perfomace better?

There is indeed an `async` version of the `ReadToEnd` method called `ReadToEndAsync` but it won't actually make your code any faster and you cannot call it from a property since properties cannot be marked as `async`.

It makes no sense to create a new `Stream` in the getter of the source property and in the setter of the same each time the property is changed.

You should read from the stream *once*, for example in the constructor of the view model or the Execute method of a command, and then set the value of the `string` property. Then you convert the `string` back to a stream *once* by the time you actually need to save it to the database, e.g:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(StreamObject.text, Encoding.UTF8, true))
            Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //this method is called when your "Save" button or similar is clicked
    public void SaveToDb()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            var str = value;
            using (textStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(textStream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
                {
                    writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
                }
                textStream.Position = 0;
                StreamObject.text = null;
                StreamObject.text = textStream;
            }
        }
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

The source property itself should not know anything about the stream.

Comment: hmm, thank you for goo strategy. I will use "read" part of it. But, in my redactor Save button activates when `StreamObject.text` modifies.

Comment: You should probably modify it to activate when the Text property is modified then.